# Eager Load with Limit on Users per Group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have simple list of Groups with Users listed in it.

```
$groups = Group::with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('last_login', 'ASC');
}])->get();
```

By that code I get all data.

[image]

My goal is to limit max users in that list to 10 per every list. Problem is when I add ->limit(10) to the code... I limit all users in all groups. So if I have 10 groups I will propably get 1 user in every group.

```
$groups = Group::with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('last_login', 'ASC')->limit(10);
}])->get();
```

My question is how can I limit that to 10 users per group.

By now withound ->limit(10) I cant get my results with that code in foreach...

```
@if ($loop->iteration == 10)
        @break
@endif
```

But it's not perfect in terms of optymalization, because I always have all users and show only 10.

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in looking at https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Answer (score 0):

You can have to use offset or the skip() method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->offset(10)
                ->limit(5)
                ->get();
```

or

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

In this example, offset/skip is how number of rows you want to skip, and then take the next 5 values. In this case, it will skip the first 10, and bring you the data from rows 10-15. You will have to pass the value of offset to your controller everytime.

If you don't want to do any of this, you can use laravels pagination:

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(15);
```

15 being the number of data you want to show per page. Return this to your view, and you will display it like this:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach

{{ $users->links() }}
```

This works for larave 5.*, just search the right documentation for the version you are using.

[Laravel Pagination Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

[Laravel 5.3 Skip Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

In fact trying to do 1 query in the database to fetch the top X records of each group in a group by statement is a complex thing to do, usually achieved by using variables, temporary tables, special functions, unions or other kind of tricks.

Then, trying to achieve this through a framework's data model binding it raises the complexity even more.

I would instead suggest you to do N+1 queries (where N would be limited to a max constant hopefully) where N is the number of groups you have.

So, here is what I mean.

Fetch the list of groups, and here make sure you limit the max, it wouldn't make sense to fetch a huge number of groups anyway, and that way you make sure you don't get bad performance for making too many queries.

```
$group_list = Group::orderBy('somethingYouLikeHere')->limit(20)->get();
```

Then you iterate over that group list to fetch the top X users:

```
$all_groups_data = [];
foreach ($group_list as $group) {
    $users = User::where('group_id', $group->id)->orderBy('last_login', 'ASC')->limit(10)->get();
    $all_groups_data[$group->id] = $users;
}
// You could also consider using a collection instead of an array
```

And there you go.
Usually you would prefer a fancy query that brings everything up at once, but in this case that would probably end up with a really complex code and query that would be hard to understand and decrypt.
With this the performance should be fine and you get the results in a short and readable code.

I hope it helps.

**Update**

You can even paginate the page if there are many groups.
To do that you just need to use the `paginate()` function in the first query that fetches the groups.